# Сортировка двумерного массива методом обмена (Си)

Tags: c, алгоритм, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Не могу дойти до решения задачи. Есть двумерный массив, заполненный случайными числами. Необходимо отсортировать по столбцам от наименьшего к наибольшему с помощью алгоритма. Задача стоит в том, чтобы изменить рабочий алгоритм для одномерного массива(вектора) под двумерный массив.

**Алгоритм, для вектора:**

```
R = N - 1;
while(R > 0) {
    k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
        if (A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
            tmp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[i + 1];
            A[i + 1] = tmp;
            k = i;
        }
    }
    R = k;
}
```

**Входящий массив:**

| 5 | 6 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | 7 | 9 |
| 1 | 8 | 11 |

**Результат:**

| 0 | 4 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 9 |
| 2 | 6 | 10 |
| 3 | 7 | 11 |

Пытался сделать для двухмерного массива вот так, как в нижнем примере, но не получается перейти с первого столбца на второй(попытки перейти убрал). Делал кучу условий на контроль позиции и левого положения относительно начала, но к успеху не пришел.

```
left = 0;
for(int left = 0; left < N; left++) {
    down = M - 1;
    while(down > 0){
        k = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < down; i++) {
          if (A[i][left] > A[i + 1][left]) {
                tmp = A[i][left];
                A[i][left] = A[i + 1][left];
                A[i + 1][left] = tmp;
                k = i;
            }
        }
        down = k;
    }
}
```

**Результат этого кода:**

| 1 | 6 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 7 | 4 |
| 3 | 8 | 9 |
| 5 | 10 | 11 |

В задаче запрещено использовать дополнительные массивы, только методом перестановки элементов. Как можно его переделать, чтобы он выполнял задачу?

Comment: А что если представить двухмерный массив в виде одномерного и сортировать обычным способом, как одномерные сортируют?

Comment: Проще всего - забросьте данные в новый временный массив, отсортируйте его и верните данные назад в отсортированном порядке. Второй вариант - очень аккуратно расписать функцию, получающую два индекса и возвращающую один, "по столбцам", и наоборот...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаете функции перерасчета индексов из одномерного массива в двумерный. `geti` - индекс по строкам, `getj` - индекс по столбцам
В закомментированном блоке - сортировка по строкам, т.е. как одномерный массив.
Меняете функции `geti` и `getj` и размерность со строк на столбцы и получаете сортировку по столбцам.

```
int geti(int i, int col) { return i / col; }
int getj(int i, int col) { return i % col; }
     
int main(void)
{
    int K=4, L=3;
    int N = K * L;
    int M[K][L] = { {  5,  6,  4},
                    {  3, 10,  0},
                    {  2,  7,  9},
                    {  1,  8, 11}};
    int R = N - 1;
    int k;
    
/*
    while(R > 0) 
    {
        k = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        {
            if (M[geti( i, L)][getj( i, L)] > M[geti( i+1, L)][getj( i+1, L)]) 
            {
                int tmp = M[geti( i, L)][getj( i, L)];
                M[geti( i, L)][getj( i, L)] = M[geti( i+1, L)][getj( i+1, L)];
                
                M[geti( i+1, L)][getj( i+1, L)] = tmp;
                k = i;
            }
        }    
        R = k;
    }
*/
   
    while(R > 0) 
    {
        k = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        {
            if (M[getj( i, K)][geti( i, K)] > M[getj( i+1, K)][geti( i+1, K)]) 
            {
                int tmp = M[getj( i, K)][geti( i, K)];
                M[getj( i, K)][geti( i, K)] = M[getj( i+1, K)][geti( i+1, K)];
                M[getj( i+1, K)][geti( i+1, K)] = tmp;
                k = i;
            }
        }    
        R = k;
    }

    std::cout << "\n"; // вывод двумерного массива как одномерного 
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        std::cout << M[geti( i, L)][getj( i, L)] << " ";
    
    std::cout << "\n";
    for(int i=0; i<K; i++)
    {   
        for(int j=0; j<L; j++)
            std::cout << M[i][j] << "\t";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
   
}
```